# What's the difference between remote_ip and peer?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm writing a plug which put the access log into a file, like mediocre web server. As the data source of client's IP address, `conn` has `remote_ip` and `peer`. Which should I use, and what's the difference between them?

Is there any documents which describe about the each entities in `conn`?

Also, my plug is like the following snippets, is it natural from Elixir/Phoenix point of view?

```
Logger.info(
  Enum.join([
    "type:" <> "request",
    "remoteip:" <> Enum.join(Tuple.to_list(conn.remote_ip), ","),
    "method:" <> conn.method,
    "path:" <> conn.request_path,
    "status:" <> to_string(conn.status),
    "size_res:" <> to_string(byte_size(to_string(conn.resp_body))),
  ], ",")
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Plug.Conn](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html) docs:

> peer - the actual TCP peer that connected, example: {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 12345}. Often this is not the actual IP and port of the client, but rather of a load-balancer or request-router.
>
> remote_ip - the IP of the client, example: {151, 236, 219, 228}. This field is meant to be overwritten by plugs that understand e.g. the X-Forwarded-For header or HAProxy’s PROXY protocol. It defaults to peer’s IP.

If you are using a load balancer (such as http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html) then the `peer` ip address will refer to the load balancer and not the client. Load balancers provide the actual IP address of the client in a header (`X-Forwarded-For` for AWS) that will be stored in the Plug.Conn struct as `remote_ip`.

See also https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239

Comment: Thank you for the detail description and URL!! I read Plug.Conn docs, I missed the part...